# IE11 ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

When I am calling requestwidgets function under document.ready it is successfully getting called and call to handler is made.
But when the same function i am calling from some function it is not getting called 
Note: This is only happening in IE11 browser
Below is the code

```
function CreateNewWidget() {
    $elementName = $("#ux_widget_name").val();
    $elementType = $("#ux_widget_type_dll").val();

    $url = '?request=newelement&elementtype=' + $elementType + '&appguid=' + appguid + '&elementname=' + $elementName;

    $.get($url, function (data) {
        if (data == "True") {
            RequestWidgets();
        }
        setTimeout("$.fn.slickBox.close()", 3000);
    });

}

var elements = Array();

function RequestWidgets() {
    $.get('/shared/test2.ashx?request=getelements&appguid=' + appguid, function (data) {
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
        elements = Array();
        RenderElements(elements);
    });
}
```

Comment: You know you're always passing an empty array to `RenderElements` ?

Comment: Yes I do Know.But ajax call(/shared/test2.ashx?request=getelements&appguid=' + appguid) is not getting made when it is getting called from Create New Widget function but when i write same code on document.ready it is getting called.That's an issue for me :(

Comment: Its probably the location it is in. Since it works from `$(document).ready()`, that means that your script is probably being placed incorrectly, probably after the "calling" code. Please provide more information so that we can inspect it better.

Comment: How are you calling `CreateNewWidget()` ?

Comment: I have put alert inside Request widgets funciton, and that alert is coming, but that ajax call is not getting executed

Comment: how are you defining `appguid ` ? you should pass this variable to each function

Comment: if you're using Chrome, use DEVELOPER TOOLS (right click on the page and go to Inspect Element) http://developer.chrome.com/devtools and check the Network tab. What kind of response are you getting?